# how to add custom functionality after woocommerce place order button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, one-time-password, woocommerce-theming

I am creating a plugin to send a one time password (OTP) to the user when the place order button is clicked. When the user clicks the button, the number from the phone number field must be captured and an API must be called to send the OTP. After that  a page with an input text box to enter the OTP must be present. If the user doesn't verify the order with the OTP, it must not be placed.

I am unable to find any hook to place such a textbox area and for the order placing.

Comment: woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout is a hook which will help you.

Comment: Using woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout hook how can stop the order from being placed?

Comment: You have asked for hook now try to do some code there and let us know if you stuck at any where,

Comment: I want a hook at the place order button not proceed to checkout button.

Comment: read about this hook first, don't assume with its name.

Comment: I have already read about the hook and implemented also the function associated with the hook is being called when the proceed to checkout button is clicked.

Comment: Use the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` action hook to show your box in the single product page. For the part of processing the info, I guess it depends on what you can think. I don't suppose there is a single solution to it.